# How can I debug spawn-fcgi?

Tags: spawn-fcgi

I'm trying to set up Munin 2.0.9 on Ubuntu with Nginx, so I'm launching `munin-cgi-graph` with the following command:

```
spawn-fcgi -s /var/run/munin/fastcgi-graph.sock -U www-data -u www-data -g www-data /usr/lib/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph
```

I get "spawn-fcgi: child spawned successfully: PID: 23886", but when I look in the list of running processes (using `ps -elf`) there is no process 23886.  I get a "502 Bad Gateway" when I hit the webserver.

How can I get spawn-fcgi up and working?  I can't find any instructions for debugging it.

Comment: Try adding `-n` to the `spawn-fcgi` command to prevent it from forking. If that doesn't help, execute `munin-cgi-graph` manually as the `www-data` user.

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions for munin log files. 
I got exactly same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 and found that log files in /var/log/munin was owned by www-data:adm. 
After chown munin:munin fcgi processes started normally. 
Hope that will help you.

Comment: @DeerHunter Why not?

Comment: @DeerHunter To debug spawn-fcgi apps you should run binary file with same user and data input without spawn-fcgi wrapper. I made this and noticed log-related error.